# Setting multiple redirects in a Netlify.toml file

Tags: html, netlify, toml

I am new to Netlify config things, so any help is appreciated. I am setting up a vanilla html, css, and javascript site through Netlify and I want to make it so if I link to `https://example.com/about` then they are served the `about.html` page. Can I do something similar to this in my `netlify.toml` file?
If I don't include the `from = "/*"` then I can't access the site, but I am wanting to route from `/reset-password` to the page `reset-password.html` Again, any help is appreciated!

```
    from = "/*"
    to = "/index.html"
    status = 200
    from = "/reset-password"
    to = "/reset-password.html"
    status = 200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a [[redirects]] header for each redirect rule:

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200

[[redirects]]
  from = "/reset-password"
  to = "/reset-password.html"
  status = 200
```

Answer (score 2):

Technically, [Slakinov's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70008265/8711564) is wrong.

it will always use the first match it finds when processing redirect rules and ignore any subsequent matches.

So

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/reset-password"
  to = "/reset-password.html"
  status = 200

[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200
```

Answer (score 0):

As I studied the rest of the day, I found out that any `.html` files will exist as routes and so there is no need for redirects. if you want to link to `example.com/about` you just create an `about.html` page and it will automatically be served at that endpoint.